# how to make table 1 look like table 2? I tried some group by functions but I don't know how to compare one record vs the other

Tags: sql, oracle

I want a select query that makes table 1 look like table 2. Meaning I want a query that will give me records that match in mem_no, join_date, end_date, product_id but do not match in Indicator. The indicator combination I am looking at is (PR vs SN) and (SR and SN). Meaning, I want records that have same mem_no, join_date, end_date, product_id but have 'PR' as indicator and 'SN' the next time or 'SR' as indicator or 'SN' next time.

```
Table 1:

mem_no  join_date   end_date    product_id  Indicator
1   2/11/2018   12/12/2018  1   PR
2   2/11/2018   12/12/2018  1   PR
2   2/11/2018   12/12/2018  1   SN
3   3/5/2017    12/12/2018  8   SR
3   3/5/2017    12/12/2018  8   SN
4   3/5/2017    12/12/2018  86  PR
4   3/5/2017    12/12/2018  86  PR
4   3/5/2017    12/12/2018  87  SR
4   3/5/2017    12/12/2018  87  SN


Table 2:
mem_no  join_date   end_date    product_id  Indicator
2   2/11/2018   12/12/2018  1   PR
2   2/11/2018   12/12/2018  1   SN
4   3/5/2017    12/12/2018  87  SR
4   3/5/2017    12/12/2018  87  SN
```

Comment: what do you mean by that but have 'PR' as indicator and 'SN' the next time or 'SR' as indicator or 'SN' next time. just have to compare two values from the table is not it??

Comment: If all the other columns are same and but in one record there is 'PR' and in another record, there is 'SN', I want those records. Also , I want records If all the other columns are same and but in one record there is 'SR' and in another record, there is 'SN'

Comment: Why don't you expect the `mem_no = 3`in the result? All columns except `Indicator`  are the same in two rows and the Indocators are `SR` and  `SN`.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber  you're right, I should have included member no 3 in table 2 (query result) also. Now, do you understand it? I was able to do my query by hardcode because there are only 3 values in indicator - SR, SN AND PR. what if there were 50 or 60 distinct indicator values?

Comment: You can scale `Indicator_lst in ('PR,SN','SN,SR')` with `Indicator_lst in (select lst from config_tab)` where `config_tab` contains all allowed combination of indicators.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want `EXISTS`:

```
select t.*
from table1 t1
where Indicator in ('PR', 'SN', 'SR') and
      exists (select 1 
              from table1 t11 
              where t11.mem_no = t.mem_no and t11.join_date = t.join_date and t11.end_date = t1.end_date and 
                    t11.product_id = t.product_id and t11.Indicator <> t.Indicator
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

[Analytic functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) are your friends

```
with data as (
select 
 mem_no, join_date, end_date, product_id, Indicator,
count(*) over (partition by mem_no, join_date, end_date, product_id) as cnt,
listagg(Indicator, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Indicator)
  over (partition by mem_no, join_date, end_date, product_id) Indicator_lst  
from tab)
select mem_no, join_date, end_date, product_id, Indicator
from data
where cnt = 2 and
Indicator_lst in ('PR,SN','SN,SR');
```

The CTO calculates the count of the rows with *same mem_no, join_date, end_date, product_id*.  The `listagg` concatenates the indicators.
The main query filters the two conditions you want.

On your sample data you get

```
MEM_NO JOIN_DATE           END_DATE            PRODUCT_ID INDICATOR
---------- ------------------- ------------------- ---------- ---------
     2 02-11-2018 00:00:00 12-12-2018 00:00:00          1 PR        
     2 02-11-2018 00:00:00 12-12-2018 00:00:00          1 SN        
     3 03-05-2017 00:00:00 12-12-2018 00:00:00          8 SN        
     3 03-05-2017 00:00:00 12-12-2018 00:00:00          8 SR        
     4 03-05-2017 00:00:00 12-12-2018 00:00:00         87 SN        
     4 03-05-2017 00:00:00 12-12-2018 00:00:00         87 SR
```

Comment: i ran the query, but it says missing right paranthesis. I tried to enter here and there but did not execute. Still have the same error.

Comment: Which version of Oracle you use? The *subquery factoring* (`with ..`) works fine from 11g. Any change you are on 10?